# MySQL query error 1064(4200) but everything seems fine

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table that I've migrated from sqlite3 but I keep getting this error

```
MariaDB [imperial]> CREATE TABLE Show( 
-> `id` int(10), 
-> `name` varchar(255), 
-> `poster_link` varchar(255), 
-> `descriptions` varchar(255), 
-> `genre_tags` varchar(255), 
-> `imdb_link` varchar(255), 
-> PRIMARY KEY(id)
-> );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Show( 
`id` int(10), 
`name` varchar(255), 
`poster_link` varchar(255), 
`descri' at line 1
```

any idea?
Heres my full query

```
CREATE TABLE Show( 
`id` int(10), 
`name` varchar(255), 
`poster_link` varchar(255), 
`descriptions` varchar(255), 
`genre_tags` varchar(255), 
`imdb_link` varchar(255), 
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

and yes I have checked the reserved words.

Comment: Change your database name to something else other than `show`. `show` is used for `show databases;` or `show columns`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the name of the table in `` since this is a keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE `Show`( 
    `id` int(10), 
    `name` varchar(255), 
    `poster_link` varchar(255), 
    `descriptions` varchar(255), 
    `genre_tags` varchar(255), 
    `imdb_link` varchar(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

But as @hcheung says, it's better to avoid keywords as object names.